# Prompting user to enter string until string starts with "A" then prints longest string

Tags: python, python-3.x

#### Problem

I'm trying to write a program where (1) the user inputs lines until he enters a line that has "A" in position 0 of the input, (2) then the program will print the line that had greater length.

The desired output is:

```
Enter a string: Faces all glow.
Enter a string: Time for summer fun 
Enter a string: As the happy faces show.
Longest string: "As the happy faces show."
```

#### Attempt

This is what I tried at first but it doesn't work at all.

```
a, b, c, d, e, f, g = input("Enter seven values: ").split()
print("Enter a String: ", a)
print("Enter a String: ", b)
print("Enter a String: ", c)
print("Enter a String: ", d)
print("Enter a String: ", e)
print("Enter a String: ", f)
print("Enter a String: ", g)
print()
```

Comment: The code part confused me a lot.

Comment: What do you mean on "I am struggling to work out how to achieve this as using letters instead of numbers has gotten the better of me."? You have any code already or you want It from scratch?

Comment: You can't enter a multi-line strings with `input`, so you will need a loop that calls it repeatedly (i.e. until a string that starts with an `"A"` is entered).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I must say what you are expecting and your sample code are not relevant at all. However, I think you are asking something like the following code can do

```
longestString = ""
a = " "
while a[0].capitalize() != 'A':
    a = input("Enter a String: ")
    if not a:
        a = " "
    if len(a) > len(longestString):
        longestString = a
    
print(longestString)
```

Comment: I would prefer not to capitalize() the letter since the question did not mention "A" or "a".

Comment: empty input would crash the program

Comment: Added empty check

Answer (score 1):

Use a while loop and a flag (boolean variable) to achieve this:

```
#initialize
stringWithA = False  #a flag, will be set to True if user enters string starting with A
currentMaxLength = 0
currentLongestStr = ''

while stringWithA == False: #haven't seen a string starting with A so far
    x = input("Enter a string: ")
    if x[0] == 'A':
        stringWithA = True
    if len(x) > currentMaxLength:
        currentMaxLength = len(x)
        currentLongestStr = x
print('"' + currentLongestStr + '"')
```

Comment: Empty input would crash the program

Answer (score 1):

Your wording seems quite confusing and other comments seem to agree with me, but from what I understand the following code should give you the desired output:

```
inp = " "
longestString = ""
while inp[0] != 'A':
    inp = input("Enter a String: ")
    if len(inp) > len(longestString):
        longestString = inp
    # To make sure empty input does not break code
    if len(inp) == 0:
        inp+=" "
    continue
print("Longest string: ", longestString)
```

Answer (score 1):

###### A similar solution but with consideration to lines with the **same length** that it is the **longest length**.

```py
inp = " "

longest = list()
length = 0

while inp[0] != 'A':
    inp = input("Enter a String: ")

    if len(inp) > length:
        longest.clear()
        length = len(inp)
        # append will happen in the next if 

    if len(inp) == length:
        longest.append(inp)

    inp += " " # to avoid empty input

print("Longest :")
for x in longest:
    print(x)
```

##### Notes

- Most of the answers stop getting input after 'A' or 'a' when the question says only 'A'.